# Unable to update open source qt version from 5.13.1 to 6.5.2 on windows 10 for visual studio 2019?

Tags: qt, qt6, qt5.5

I have open source qt 5.13.1 on windows 10. I want to upgrade qt to 6.5.2 to be used on windows 10 for visual studio 2019.

Earlier version like 5.13.1 used to provide qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.13.1.exe ( [*https://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/5.13/5.13.0/*]). But similar exe is not available for 6.5.2 ( [*https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/6.5/6.5.2/*] ) to install the needed version.

Tried to run the maintainence.exe. But the mirror  *https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/qt/archive/online_installers/4.6/qt-unified-windows-x64-4.6.1-online.exe* is not reachable with errors "***This page isn’t working mirrors.cloud.tencent.com didn’t send any data.***".

Tried using other mirrors( *listed in https://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/windows_x86/root/qt/Updates.xml.mirrorlist* ) too using command like this `*MaintenanceTool.exe --mirror https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/qt`*. But which ever repo I use I get **error " *at least one valid and enabled repository required for this action to succeed*"**.

How do I update the open source qt from 5.13.1 to 6.5.2 on windows?